# trying to call multiple functions but only getting response from one

Tags: php

I am trying to call multiple functions, each function establishes a socket connection and returns data from a particular web site.. but I have found when I call the functions, i am only getting response back from 1 of them. However, they do each work individually.

This is how I am making the call:

```
bad_cipher_test($url);
good_cipher_test1($url);
good_cipher_test2($url);
```

I would like them to work sequentially.. after the first function is complete go to the next..

-- RESOLVED --

It turned out the calls were timing out because of so many ciphers in the array. I had to set the timeout to indefinite `set_time_limit(0);`

Comment: not sure what happen to all the comments ??? anyway, setting the timeout at the top of the page fixed the issue `set_time_limit(0);`

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer and accept it. (http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: thx. will have to wait 2 days to accept it

Answer (score 1):

It turned out the calls were timing out because of so many ciphers in the array. I had to set the timeout to indefinite `set_time_limit(0);`